# Cakephp insert into with select using model

Tags: mysql, cakephp, select, model, insert

Can I create this query in cakephp using model?

```
INSERT INTO table (name,age)
SELECT name, age
FROM table2
WHERE age >= 50
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I imagined something similar to create a query to select something equal to 
array (
'table' => 'table' 
'conditions' => array (...) 
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

The ugly one: Use [Model::query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query). **DO NOT USE THIS UNLESS IT IS ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY**

The decent one: (I am not going to give you a copy/paste solution, instead I will give you the idea)

- Get all data from the model2 ($data = $Model2->find('all', array('conditions' => ...
- Apply (if needed) some format to the variable that contains your results
- Use [Model::saveMany()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Comment: I know Model :: query, 
If I use saveMany, cakephp will perform several queries to insert, 
I liked only one query to do the work

Comment: @ThamerMazzucaMartins any particular reason for that? anyways, you can still do it in one query with a transaction. Read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html)

Comment: @GuillermoMansilla I thought I could build the query using commands cake so he could create as much as in postgre query in mysql instead of using the own query that works only on mysql

Comment: I don't understand what your saying, the Model layer doesn't care if you're database is Mysql or Postgres, this layer will build the query in such a way that the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This still comes up in search, so here's the update.

> Generally, it is easier to insert data using entities and save(). By composing a SELECT and INSERT query together, you can create INSERT INTO ... SELECT style queries:
>
> ```
> $select = $articles->find()
>     ->select(['title', 'body', 'published'])
>     ->where(['id' => 3]);
>
> $query = $articles->insertQuery()
>     ->insert(['title', 'body', 'published'])
>     ->values($select)
>     ->execute();
> ```

The above is for CakePHP 5. Available for:

- CakePHP 3: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data
- CakePHP 4: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data
- CakePHP 5: https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/orm/query-builder.html#inserting-data

(See the third example.)

Note the little code/method name differences, e.g. `insertQuery()` is called `query()` in CakePHP 3.